# Error : NBTSol.Models.ContactDbContext.Persons is inaccessible due to its protection level -C#

Tags: entity-framework

i am using entity framework in windowformapplication , when i call "db.Persons.Add()" it doesn't show refernce for Persons and gives the error :

Error : NBTSol.Models.ContactDbContext.Persons is inaccessible due to its protection level
even everything is public,

then why?

Person Model :

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace NBTSol.Models
 {
   public class Person
   {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is Required")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is Required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is Required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is Required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PostalCode is Required")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is Required")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Number is Required")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNIC is Required")]
    public string CNIC { get; set; }


    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> IsClient { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }

 }
}
```

My Context Class :

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Data.Entity;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;

     namespace NBTSol.Models
     {
     public class ContactDbContext :DbContext
     {
    public ContactDbContext() : base( "name=DefaultConnection") { }

    DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure domain classes using Fluent API here

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
   }
  }
```

main form :[here is the error when i try to call "db.Persons.Add()"]

```
 using NBTSol.Models;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace NBTSol
  {
   public partial class Main : Form
   {
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContactDbContext db = new ContactDbContext();
        Person person = new Person();
        db.Persons.Add(person);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Person` property public in your db context as following and it will work.

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

Replace your ContactDbContext class with following code:

```
public class ContactDbContext: DbContext {
 public ContactDbContext(): base("name=DefaultConnection") {}

 public DbSet < Person > Persons {
  get;
  set;
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  //Configure domain classes using Fluent API here

  //Configure table name
  modelBuilder.Entity<Persons>()
  .ToTable("Persons ");

  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
}
```

Comment: There is another Issue , i have declared my model as Person and pluralize it to Persons in DbContext class as per covention..but it is creating People table in database Instead of Creating Persons but Columns are same as decalred in model

Comment: I have update my answer to set table name to `Persons`. Check `OnModelCreating` method.